# Why is $T(X) = X_{1} + ... + X_{n}$ a sufficient statistics for Poisson $\lambda$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}\sum{X_{i}}$

Tags: poisson-distribution, sufficient-statistics

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Poisson_distribution):

> If $X_{1},\dots, X_{n}$ are independent and have a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, then the sum $T(X) = X_{1} + ... + X_{n}$ is a sufficient statistic for $\lambda$.

Why the sufficient statistics for $\lambda$ is not $\frac{1}{n}\sum{X_{i}}$ instead?

I struggle to understand how the sum of the observations can say anything about the mean ($\lambda$) of the distribution that generated the observations. The vectors of observations `3 6 2 2` and `3 6 2 2 0 2 2 0 7 2` have different sums but they are generated from the same distribution with $\lambda = 3$.

I suspect my question is a duplicate of [Sufficient statistic for Poisson in wiki?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/389163/sufficient-statistic-for-poisson-in-wiki) by I'm afraid I still don't get it.

Comment: One is a bijective transform of the other, hence they are equivalent.

Answer (score 5):

If $n$ is known, both are sufficient. More generally, any statistic which is in 1-1 correspondence with a sufficient statistic, is sufficient. What matters is the partition different values of the statistic induce in the sample space, not the particular values of the sufficient statistic.

Comment: *What matters is the partition different values of the statistic induce in the sample space, not the particular values of the sufficient statistic.* But then a sufficient statistics for the mean $\theta$ of a normal distribution could also be $\sum{X_{i}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}\sum{X_{i}}$ as reported on Wikipedia? I surmise the answer is no... but why?

Comment: Right. If $n$ is known, both are sufficient for the mean of a normal. (Both give the same information, you can always obtain one from the other.)

Comment: (Thanks for your patience) You say *If n is known*. My understanding is/was that a sufficient statistic gives you everything you need to know to estimate the parameter of interest. For me, this means the $n$ cannot be assumed to be known. Or is $n$  "allowed" because it's a property of the sample rather than a statistic about the population?

Comment: If $n$ is not known, then neither $\bar{X}$ nor $\sum X_i$ are sufficient for the mean. If $n$ is known, then either are sufficient. It may be clearer if you take a specific situation. Suppose $n=100$. Someone tells you that $\bar{X}=3.18$. Then, you automatically know that $\sum X_i=318$. On the other hand, if they told you that  $\sum X_i=318$, then you would know $\bar{X}$. They both have the same information from the sample because once you know one, you know the other.

Comment: @JohnL - I feel dumb here - If you tell me that $\bar{X} = 3.18$ then I don't need to know what $n$ was. On the other hand, $\sum{X_{i}} = 318$ is meaningless without knowing $n$. If I'm allowed to communicate just **one** number for the estimate of $\mu$, then  $\bar{X}$ is not only better but is also everything the receiver of my communication needs to know. The same cannot be said about the $\sum{X_{i}}$ (That's my informal understanding of sufficient statistic).

Comment: @dariober, $n$ has sort of a special status, yes. Together with $\sum X_i$ allows you to estimate the mean, even though by itself carries no information whatsoever about it.

Comment: @F.Tusell Thanks again - *n  has sort of a special status* that's what I came to realize and wasn't clear to me before. Once $n$ is known, it's easy to see why $\sum{X_{i}}$ and $\bar{X}$ are in 1-1 correspondence. And $n$ has special status because it doesn't depend on the population the sample came from.